# JSON response always returns zero for int value

Tags: android, json, retrofit2

I call HTTP request with retrofit library and get results from an API. I configure log in retrofit library so i could see what's going on. The response is a simple primitive integer type.
The **problem** is that it always returns zero. Response class(LoginModel) is also a classic class with one setter and one getter for integer type.

```
public class LoginModel {

  @SerializedName("result")
  private int result;

  public void setResult(int result){
    this.result = result;
  }

  public int getResult(){
    return result;
  }
}
```

Below image is my log which you can see i got response 10 but when i log *getResult* in onResponse function, it prints always zero.

```
Log.i("BODY : ", String.valueOf(response.body().getResult()));
```

[image]

I can't figure out whats wrong. I appreciate any help. thanks

UPDATE:  full code of calling API

```
Call<LoginModel> isSended = apiService.sendCode(phoneNumber);
            isSended.enqueue(new Callback<LoginModel>() {
                @Override
                public void onResponse(Call<LoginModel> call, Response<LoginModel> response) {
                    Log.i("BODY : ", String.valueOf(response.body().getResult()));
                    if (!response.isSuccessful()) {
                        Toast.makeText(context, context.getResources().getString(R.string.errorServer), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                        dismissProgressBarDialog();
                        return;
                    }
                    myTimer = new MyTimer(SECOND_TIME, 1000);
                    views.reactionActivationPress(response.body().getResult());
                }

                @Override
                public void onFailure(Call<LoginModel> call, Throwable t) {
                    Log.i(Constant.NETWORK_LOG, "sendCode : " + t.toString());
                    dismissProgressBarDialog();
                    Toast.makeText(MyApplication.getContext(), "Server Problem", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                }
            });
```

Code of Gson and Retrofit creation:

```
OkHttpClient client = new OkHttpClient.Builder()
                    .connectTimeout(30, TimeUnit.SECONDS)
                    .readTimeout(30, TimeUnit.SECONDS)
                    .addInterceptor(loggingInterceptor)
                    .addInterceptor(chain -> {
                        Request request = chain.request();
                        Request newRequest;
                        newRequest = request.newBuilder()
                                .addHeader(HEADER_VERSION_CODE, String.valueOf(BuildConfig.VERSION_CODE))
                                .build();
                        return chain.proceed(newRequest);
                    })
                    .build();

            Gson gson = new GsonBuilder()
                    .setLenient()
                    .create();

            retrofit = new Retrofit.Builder()
                    .baseUrl(BASE_URL)
                    .client(client)
                    .addConverterFactory(ScalarsConverterFactory.create())
                    .addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create(gson))
                    .addCallAdapterFactory(RxJava2CallAdapterFactory.create())
                    .build();
```

Comment: share your code to call api with interface.

Comment: Use @Expose with SerializedName annotation and try again, if the problem persists add your code and response string as json you getting in logs

Comment: @MehulKabaria - I update my question and put my code for calling api as u wanted.

Comment: @PJain - json response is in image. OkHttp logs the json. **{"result":10}**

Comment: have you tried that using @Expose annotation with SerializedName?

Comment: then you need to try with the debugger help with debug code line by line

Comment: I know all variables values and other things. I don't know why. how does debug help with the cause of that or help to solve it?

Answer (score 4):

There is no problem with the code. It works well. 
Make sure you are using Gson with retrofit.
I've tested the code and its working well. No need to make changes in model class.

Comment: Share your code where you are adding GsonConverter in retrofit. That could fix it

Comment: There was problem somewhere else. I disabled Minify and Shrink feature in build variant and it's gone!

Answer (score 4):

```
        ApiClient.getClient().create(ApiService.class).sendCode(phoneNumber).enqueue(new Callback<LoginModel>() {
            @Override
            public void onResponse(Call<LoginModel> call, Response<LoginModel> response) {
                Log.i("BODY : ", String.valueOf(response.body().getResult()));
                if (!response.isSuccessful()) {
                    Toast.makeText(context, context.getResources().getString(R.string.errorServer), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                    dismissProgressBarDialog();
                    return;
                }
                myTimer = new MyTimer(SECOND_TIME, 1000);
                views.reactionActivationPress(response.body().getResult());
            }

            @Override
            public void onFailure(Call<LoginModel> call, Throwable t) {
                Log.i(Constant.NETWORK_LOG, "sendCode : " + t.toString());
                dismissProgressBarDialog();
                Toast.makeText(MyApplication.getContext(), "Server Problem", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }
        });
```

Comment: Your little example here helped me remove about a 100 lines of redundant code from my app. Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

you issue in code is you are trying to access result twice in respons please try as below

declare it only once  `response.body().getResult()`

```
    Call<LoginModel> isSended = apiService.sendCode(phoneNumber);
                    isSended.enqueue(new Callback<LoginModel>() {
                        @Override
                        public void onResponse(Call<LoginModel> call, Response<LoginModel> response) {

                        dismissProgressBarDialog();
                        int model = response.body().getResult();                   
                        Log.i("BODY : ", String.valueOf(model));
                            if (!response.isSuccessful()) {
                                Toast.makeText(context, context.getResources().getString(R.string.errorServer), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

                                return;
                            }
                            myTimer = new MyTimer(SECOND_TIME, 1000);
                            views.reactionActivationPress(model);
                        }

                        @Override
                        public void onFailure(Call<LoginModel> call, Throwable t) {
                            Log.i(Constant.NETWORK_LOG, "sendCode : " + t.toString());
                            dismissProgressBarDialog();
                            Toast.makeText(MyApplication.getContext(), "Server Problem", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                        }
                    });
```

Comment: result is an integer not the LoginModel. whole response.body() is an object of LoginModel.

Comment: replace int with LoginModel as in updated ans and try @MehranZamani

Answer (score 2):

Try to make "result" field public instead of private. I am guessing, that retrofit is ignoring your json and not initializing result field at all. Remove getter and setter and make result field public.

```
public class LoginModel {

  @SerializedName("result")
  public int result;

}
```

Comment: have you seen such model anywhere or have you got any evidence for your answer? I've got my model from http://www.jsonschema2pojo.org/

Comment: @MehranZamani The only evidence I have is almost 5 years of Android development :) Just try to make a request with this model and check if it works. You can also try to add Expose annotation to your result field in your model, then it also should work.

Comment: public class LoginModel {

  @SerializedName("result")
 @Expose
  private int result;

  public void setResult(int result){
    this.result = result;
  }

  public int getResult(){
    return result;
  }
}

Comment: I think I agree with @AndriyAntoniv, don't make it private, at least go for package protected.

Answer (score 2):

use Integer and if you got null, it's means the json u got **from server has another name or type**, ***test your api with postman*** and check the response names and type

```
public class LoginModel {

    @SerializedName("result")
    @Expose
    private Integer result;

    public void setResult(Integer result){
      this.result = result;
    }

    public Integer getResult(){
        return result;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I think there is an issue in your POJO class. **Try this it may help you**.

```
public class LoginModel implements Serializable {

    @SerializedName("result")
    @Expose
    private Integer result;

    public Integer getResult() {
        return result;
    }

    public void setResult(Integer result) {
        this.result = result;
    }

}
```